# using JDBC within dynamic web application

Tags: java, web-applications, jdbc, struts2

I have a dynamic web application using struts2 that works perfectly.

I have a JDBC application that works perfectly (all it does is print a table out in the console).

After I put the two together all that was left was to add authentication to the run configuration and I'd be done...
I've already put the sqljdbc_auth.dll to the WEB-INF/lib
I've tried to add this line to Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost

```
-Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files (x86)\jdbc\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x86"
```

but it doesn't do anything

> This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.
>   ClientConnectionId:6495...

It's the line that got my JDBC application working just fine.
Would there be some syntax error I'm missing or another method for me to pass an argument that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Please post what exception you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the Microsoft SQL Server Driver which is pure java (type 4) so you dont need to mess with java.library.path. Set the Classpath as described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526.aspx)

Alternatively include the jdbc driver in WEB-INF/lib within your WAR file.

Comment: I already tried that but it still says its not configured for integrated authentication.